# Lenovo Z70 wifi with 14.04.2 and kernel 3.16 not working

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I'm trying to install 14.04.2 on a new Lenovo Z70, replacing Win 8.1, but on this hardware but no wireless capabilities seem to be found.  [Elsewhere](https://www.quora.com/Couldnt-connect-to-WiFi-in-ubuntu-trusty-tahr-in-my-Lenovo-z50-70-can-any-one-help?share=1) I see that the 3.16 kernel is required, but 14.04.2 seems to use that kernel.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

The diagnostic output from [this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11036534/).

Comment: You wifi card is very new and is not supported in 3.16 that I know of.  Your wireless card is different than the one in the "Elsewhere" link.  A [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184/comments/115) on a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184) shows that it can work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface)

Answer (score 2):

Your very new device, Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e], is covered in the mainline kernel version 4.0: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/ The module *ath10k_pci* covers the subject device:

```
modinfo ath10k_pci
filename:       /lib/modules/4.0.1-040001-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Atheros QCA988X PCIe devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     837C8B320227AB6A933D58D
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
<snip>
```

As you can see, the driver requires firmware. My default 15.04 install includes most of it. If firmware is an issue, according to *dmesg*, I suggest you do:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware/ath10k
sudo cp -r QCA6174/  /lib/firmware/ath10k
```

Correct the permissions of the files:

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/*
```

Now unload and reload the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci  &&  sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

And check:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

I have been unable to find *cal-pci-000:03:0.0.bin* anywhere, nor any method to extract it by any means. I did read that a module parameter may help. Let's try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Check as above.

If you need guidance about how to install the 4.0 kernel, please check here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/04/upgrade-to-linux-kernel-4-0-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I installed 15.04 and the 4.0 kernel as suggested.  You can see new diagnostic info [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11044707/).  It looks like firmware is an issue according to _dmesg_.  Thanks for your help so far.  Any help with the firmware issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I think I have solved most of it. Is this a dual-boot with Windows? Is `cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin' on your Windows partition?

Comment: No, this is not dual boot.  I'm not sure about 'cal-pci-000:03:0.0.bin'.  I will try the firmware suggestions above and respond when I have results. Thanks.

Comment: Yikes.  dmesg is still reporting a bunch of errors.  New  log is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11046024/).  I appreciate you sticking with me here.  The last time I trouble shot a hardware issue it involved a 9 track mag tape reel.  Maybe that's what pushed me towards software.  :-)

Comment: Up through 3.59xx are the same as before. Please see my further edit above. My first experience was an IBM 360 and COBOL.

Comment: The _dmesg_ log is at least changing.  Here's the [new one](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11050088/).  Also, I went through all the steps again this time, starting with 15.04 reinstall, just to be sure I hadn't missed anything before.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like until we can find or bypass *cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin*, we are stuck. I will keep searching and suggest you do also. Leave a message here if you see any possibilities. FWIW, I don't believe anyone has one of these working, but you are very close.

Comment: Please see a new edit above! Reboot and paste diagnostics, please.

Comment: Doh.  That seemed promising but sadly [the new log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11051402/) doesn't look much different.

Comment: I'll keep checking.

Comment: FYI:  I tried two different usb wireless products (ASUS USB-N13 Wireless N-300, and TP-Link TL-WN823N).  With both the connection stops working after several minutes.  Disabling/enabling network and/or wifi or even rebooting has no effect.  Deleting the wifi connection then recreating it seems work.  That is, you get a few more minutes.  Highly frustrating.  Any ideas would be a appreciated.

Comment: Is this finally solved? I am having Lenovo Z70-80 and planning to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Also, I have gone through this link (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2308578) which talks about getting the firmware to have the wifi work for the Atheros QCA61x4.

Can somebody let know if this ever been made to work on Lenovo Z70-80?

Comment: @UreshKuruhuri The firmware and driver are present by default in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Thanks @chili555 for confirming. I am able to successfully install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Lenovo Z70. It is working fine.