# Ethernet connection not recognized and no WiFi options are displayed

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, drivers, kernel

This is the first time that I am using Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10 on my Lenovo Z51. And here is the first problem I am facing:

My Ethernet connection is not even recognized in Ubuntu. Plus, no option for WiFi is displayed anywhere. But both of them are connected in Windows. That means, I can't connect to internet in Ubuntu and have to restart my PC with Windows everytime I want to do so. I have tried installing `wicd` in Ubuntu but to no avail. Also, I removed `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` and restarted `network-manager`, which made no difference. I tried booting Kali Linux, Cyborg-Hawk and Ubuntu 16.04 from USB, and the problem persisted.

```
Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
```

Following screenshots of my Ubuntu desktop will make you the picture more clear.

[image: **OpenScreenshot1**]  [image: **OpenScreenshot2**]

I went to install `backath10k-dkms_2.0_all.deb` which gave me an error shown in the following screenshot:

[image: **OpenScreenshot3**]

Edit: **Ubuntu connects to the network by using a USB Externel WiFi Adapter**

Checked-out following:

```
lsmod | grep ath
dmesg | grep ath
```

[image: **OpenScreenshot4**]

Checking for `ath10k_pci`

[image: **OpenScreenshot5**]

Latest : `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`

[image: **OpenScreenshot6**]

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/678145/37165) has described similar issue for `[168c:0041] (rev 20)` WiFi device. But since your setup is a dual-boot system, it may be a [known issue due to the setup](http://superuser.com/a/981246/109256).

Comment: @clearkimura I appreciate your concern, but I am a beginner in Ubuntu and unable to understand your post. Kindly guide me, in simpler terms, through the solution.

Comment: In simpler terms, your networking devices are likely supported by Ubuntu. But Windows is having control over the networking devices and doesn't allow other system to use it. A simple workaround is to use a different hardware i.e. USB external Wi-Fi adapter instead. Software wise, there is no easy solution for this kind of issue. Other users may have better answer.

Comment: @clearkimura This is wrong. Windows can't "control" anything if you boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Chirag, is there a reason why you would want to go with a less descriptive title? We are here trying to get more attention to your question at the least and you are not helping us to help you.

Comment: I believe the needed driver `ath10k_pci` exists in kernel 4.2.0-xx. Check: `lsmod | grep ath`. If so, then the issue is firmware. Let's see what the message logs say: `dmesg | grep ath` Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 I have uploaded the resulting messages. Thanks for the concern.

Comment: Please confirm that you have ath10k_pci: `modinfo ath10k_pci | grep 0041` It may produce no output at all. If so, we need to know.

Comment: This is a known bug for the `Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164` chipset. Check this out: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940 There is a known solution in that link.

Comment: @chili555 It did produce some output

Comment: I asked for `modinfo ath10k_pci | grep 0041` because 0041 is the pci.id of your device.  You provided grep ath. In any event, I have learned that your kernel version 4.2.0-35 doesn't include 168c:0041 and  will propose an appropriate solution.

Comment: @chili555 Sorry for the mistake. `modinfo ath10k_pci | grep 0041` did not produce any result.

Comment: The non-working Ethernet adapter is probably a driver issue to. Please make a new question for it, [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and include a link to the result.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I followed the steps and here is the link:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/15960787/

Comment: I repeat: please *make a [new question](/questions/new)* for the Ethernet issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pci.id of 168c:0041 is not included in kernel version 4.2.0-xx. Let's install a newer kernel version:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-headers-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-headers-4.4.8-040408_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
sudo -i
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
exit
```

Reboot. If the correct firmware is installed, the wireless should now be working.

Comment: I got the following error:  root@chirag:~# dpkg -i linux*.deb  
dpkg: error processing archive linux*.deb (--install):  
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 linux*.deb

Comment: Oops! I'm editing the answer now. Sorry for my mis-step.

Comment: It worked ! Wireless is now working flawlessly. I have no words to appreciate your efforts.  Kindly take a look at ethernet too.

Comment: @chili555: Why not simply `sudo apt-get linux-generic-lts-xenial` instead of the first 4 lines? Otherwise good answer! +1

Comment: @DavidFoerster Just another way of doing essentially the same thing. Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour Please ask a new question about your ethernet and I will be happy to help.

Comment: @chili555: With an Apt based installation one would get automatic updates though as opposed to with the manual path suggested in your answer.

Comment: @chili555 please take a look on my [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761027/ethernet-not-working-on-ubuntu) on the ethernet issue.

Comment: @chili555 after when the wireless started to work, I somehow fixed the ethernet issue too after so much research on internet. But as soon as I updated using the command `sudo apt-get update` and restarted, the whole thing went back and again there is no wireless and ethernet.

Comment: What does this tell us? `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`?

Comment: @chili555 I've pasted the screenshot as the last image in the question with a "Latest" tag. Please take a look.

Comment: It shows a firmware crash. Please try updating it: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.162_all.deb If you need explicit instructions, I suggest you start a new question and I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Lenovo Z70 three weeks ago, and after installing Ubuntu 14.04, I was not able to use my WiFi. I was able to hard wire into the router, however.

Do I understand that you are not able to hard wire into the router?

I did a lot of research, and tried three different suggestions, and finally was able to get my wifi to work.

I followed the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621345/lenovo-z70-wifi-with-14-04-2-and-kernel-3-16-not-working). I'll spell out the instructions here, though, to hopefully make them simpler for someone new to Ubuntu (as I am).

A disclaimer: I don't understand everything that is happening under the hood. I only know that this fixed my problem.

1. I did this to get the ath10k firmware (which I was apparently missing):

   `sudo apt-get install git
   git clone https://github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware.git
   cd ath10k-firmware/ath10k
   sudo cp -r QCA6174/  /lib/firmware/ath10k`
2. To correct the permissions of the firmware file you downloaded:

   `sudo chmod +x /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/*`
3. To unload and re-load the driver:

   `sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci  &&  sudo modprobe ath10k_pci`
4. Apparently this is to incorporate a module parameter. I'm not sure what that means, but I did this, and my Wifi works now:

   `sudo -i
   echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
   exit`
5. Reboot your computer, and check.

I do have the other resources I collected when I was troubleshooting this. I believe this is a problem that our Lenovo Z-series have.

Let me know if this doesn't do anything for you, and I can look at some of the other resources I found.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but my Ethernet cable is not recognized in Ubuntu, which leaves me with no internet connection there.

Comment: I downloaded the ath10k firmware from github using windows and then followed all the steps as you directed, but there was no difference.